# position:-webkit-sticky not working on Safari

Tags: safari, sticky

I  have a problem with position sticky that does not work on Safari Mojave (updated version) for my navbar.
Vendor prefix Ok.
No overflow parent(body).
Bootstrap 4.
I tried many issues without success. Thanks a lot for your help !

```
<div id="navbar" class="header-gs-nav z-depth-1 d-none d-xl-block">
    <div class="container-full">
        <div class="header-inner">
            <div class="row m-0">
                <div class="col-2 title-logo-wrapper"></div>
                <div class="col-8 main-wrapper"></div>
                <div class="col-2 etrade-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.header-gs-nav{
background: #fff;
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1070;}
```